LWC - Cumulative value / running total calculation sorting in the opposite direction
To start, I'm not a developer.
I'm trying to create a view that shows closed opportunities, and the cumulative value / running total of the ARR on those opportunities at the time of close.
The data should be sorted by close date desc, which it is, but the Cumulative ARR data is not calculating in the right direction

If I sort by Close Date ASC, it works, but I need the newest Close Date at the top
My apex class
public with sharing class ClientProductTimelineController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<OpportunityWrapper> getOpportunities(Id accountId) {
        // SOQL Query
        List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT Name, Type, Product_Rollup_Name__c, CloseDate, Opportunity_Last_Period_ARR__c
                                   FROM Opportunity
                                   WHERE AccountId = :accountId
                                   AND Opportunity_Status__c = 'Won'
                                   ORDER BY CloseDate DESC];
        
        // Create a wrapper class to store the data and calculate cumulative ARR
        List<OpportunityWrapper> wrappedOpps = new List<OpportunityWrapper>();
        Decimal cumulativeARR = 0;

        for (Opportunity opp : opps) {
            cumulativeARR += opp.Opportunity_Last_Period_ARR__c != null ? opp.Opportunity_Last_Period_ARR__c : 0;
            wrappedOpps.add(new OpportunityWrapper(opp, cumulativeARR));
        }

        return wrappedOpps;
    }
    
    // Wrapper Class
    public class OpportunityWrapper {
        @AuraEnabled public Opportunity opportunity { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled public Decimal cumulativeARR { get; set; }
        
        public OpportunityWrapper(Opportunity opp, Decimal cumulativeARR) {
            this.opportunity = opp;
            this.cumulativeARR = cumulativeARR;
        }
    }
}

.js
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getOpportunities from '@salesforce/apex/ClientProductTimelineController.getOpportunities';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class OpportunityList extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId; // The Account Id passed to this component
    opportunities = [];
    error;

    // Fetch opportunities when accountId is set
    @wire(getOpportunities, { accountId: '$recordId' })
    wiredOpportunities({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.opportunities = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.opportunities = undefined;
            this.showErrorToast(error.body.message);
        }
    }

    showErrorToast(message) {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Error loading opportunities',
            message,
            variant: 'error',
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}

.html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Timeline" icon-name="standard:opportunity">
        <template if:true={opportunities}>
            <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Type</th>
                        <th scope="col">Product Rollup</th>
                        <th scope="col">Close Date</th>
                        <th scope="col">ARR</th>
                        <th scope="col">Cumulative ARR</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <template for:each={opportunities} for:item="opp">
                        <tr key={opp.opportunity.Id}>
                            <td>{opp.opportunity.Name}</td>
                            <td>{opp.opportunity.Type}</td>
                            <td>{opp.opportunity.Product_Rollup_Name__c}</td>
                            <td>{opp.opportunity.CloseDate}</td>
                            <td>{opp.opportunity.Opportunity_Last_Period_ARR__c}</td>
                            <td>{opp.cumulativeARR}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </template>
        <template if:true={error}>
            <p>Error loading data</p>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

Any help is appreciated. I've tried using reverse() with no luck, but probably used it in the wrong context

To start, I'm not a developer - why are you using Apex?
